# Check if key exist in one of the objects

Tags: php

I would like to check if a key exist in one of the objects :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1631]
      public 'label' => string 'Monsieur' (length=8)
      public 'value' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'selected' => boolean true
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[1633]
      public 'label' => string 'Madame' (length=6)
      public 'value' => string '2' (length=1)
```

In the example I have one array who contain two objects, the first one contain 'selected' key. I would like to return true if one of them contain 'selected' key. If the objects not contain 'selected' key I would like to return false.

I can have more than two objects. This is only for the example. Is there a function for this?

Comment: Please try something - and show that attempt.

Comment: Are you looking for isset()?

Comment: You only have one array, containing two objects though

Comment: @DarkBee yes sorry i edited the question

Comment: Use `array_filter()` with a function that checks whether the key exists.

Comment: Hi @Mathieu, it would really help if you supplied the code you have tried ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Otherwise your questions reads as "Can someone do my code for me".

Comment: @Barmar although that would look nicer - it would filter out everything that's false, think OP just wants to return false

Comment: @treyBake You just check whether the resulting array is empty or not.

Comment: @Barmar true I guess ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this work using simple loop

```
$res = false;
foreach($arr as $item){
  if (isset($item->selected)) 
    $res = true;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/fYSNI)

*Note that if your array is large, you need to `break` loop when finding target key to prevent additional checking*

---

Also you can do this work using `array_filter()`

```
$res = !!array_filter($arr, function($item){
    return isset($item['selected']);
});
```

Comment: You don't like `if` statements? This seems like a strange use of the ternary operator, since you're not using the value.

Comment: @DarkBee There are no warnings when you use `isset()`.

Comment: Pretty sure the `isset` was not there before the edit though

Comment: You should break out of the loop when you find the key.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is optional to prevent additional checking

Comment: @Mohammad working man thanks :) ... losted my mind , the solution was really easy

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you don't have an array of arrays there, you have an array of **objects**.

Simply use [property_exists](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) to check if a key is in that object - however note, that it will return **true** even if value is null.

```
var_dump(property_exists($array[1], 'key'));
```

or if you want to test using arrays ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)):

```
var_dump(array_key_exists((array) $array[1], 'key'));
```

or as a function

```
function checkInArray($array, $key)
{
    $found = array_filter($array, function($el)
    {
        return (property_exists((array) $el, $key));
    }

    return (!empty($found) ? true : false)
}

if (checkInArray($yourArray, 'selected')) {
    # do something
}
```

Comment: This only checks one object, he wants to check if *any* of the objects has the property.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just doing example code - not a copy/paste solution :) he just needs to wrap in a foreach - or array_filter as you suggested :)

Comment: You should say so in the answer, it's not obvious since you used a specific index.

Comment: @Barmar updated question with a function to use ^^ should be more self-explanatory :D lemme know if otherwise :)

Comment: Don't assume the questioner knows how to generalize. If he could figure that out, he probably wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.